# Snowflake Query Profile, Total Duration vs. Total Execution Time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm analyzing query performance in Snowflake.

When I look at the Query Profile in the Snowflake web console, like `https://xxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/console#/monitoring/queries/detail?queryId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, I see "Total Execution Time" took 190 milliseconds and I see that "Total Duration" took 2.7 seconds.

I can't figure out why there is such a vast discrepancy between the two numbers. Where can I learn the source of my extra 2.51 seconds?

[image: total duration]
[image: execution time]

I can see in Snowflake documentation that

> Execution time provides information about “where the time was spent” during the processing of a query. Time spent can be broken down into the following categories:
>
> Processing — time spent on data processing by the CPU.
>
> Local Disk IO — time when the processing was blocked by local disk access.
>
> Remote Disk IO — time when the processing was blocked by remote disk access.
>
> Network Communication — time when the processing was waiting for the network data transfer.
>
> Synchronization — various synchronization activities between participating processes.
>
> Initialization — time spent setting up the query processing.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-history.html

But a lot more "time was spent" outside that execution time and I'm trying to figure out its source.

Comment: Was your query queued for any period of time?

Comment: I don't believe so. I executed it directly in a worksheet in the console. Is there a place where one can see whether a query was queued or what the queuing time is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `snowflake.account_usage.query_history` table. It will give you a better breakdown of how long things took to run. Here is an example query:

```sql
select
    QUERY_TEXT,
    EXECUTION_STATUS,
    START_TIME,
    END_TIME,
    TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME,
    COMPILATION_TIME,
    EXECUTION_TIME,
    QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME,
    QUEUED_OVERLOAD_TIME,
    QUEUED_REPAIR_TIME,
    TRANSACTION_BLOCKED_TIME
from snowflake.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
limit 10
```

Comment: interesting. so from that perspective COMPILATION_TIME accounts for the additional 2.51 seconds.

Comment: That does seem pretty slow... Was it a large query?

Comment: It is a lot of CTEs, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Execution time is literally the time it took for the query to execute. Total duration time includes things like queuing/waiting for warehouse, reading from disk/memory, compilation of results etc.

Comment: So the Execution Time doesn't include compilation and reading from disk or memory? What is the 50% Initialization represent in the Execution Time?

Comment: according to snowflake documentation, Execution time includes reading from disk and memory. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-history.html

Comment: Apologies, I must have got confused as the docs do indeed say that (although it could be clearer). According to the below it may just be a quirk of the Web UI and what it counts from the api call: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009KB1G5SAL/what-is-exactly-total-execution-time-in-profile-overview